# .Xresources not read by urxvt running under crouton with i3wm

Tags: linux, x-windows, chromebook, urxvt, i3-window-manager

Chromebook with Linux running via crouton (originally Ubuntu 12.04, upgraded to 14.04). I'm starting X from crosh/shell using:

```
sudo i3
```

Contents of i3 (comments/usage instructions omitted):

```
#!/bin/sh/ -e

set -e
exec sh -e "`dirname "\`readlink -f "$0"\`"`/enter-chroot" -t x11 "$@" "" \
    exec xinit
```

Contents of .xinitrc:

```
#!/bin/sh
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
exec i3
```

Contents of .Xresources:

```
URxvt.scrollBar: false
```

i3 fires up as I would expect. However, after opening urxvt, `xrdb -query` yields nothing. I can explicitly run `xrdb ~/.Xresources` and `xrdb -query` returns the single line above. After this, new urxvt windows open without scrollbars.

I understood that urxvt sources .Xresources by default. Even if it didn't, I would have thought my xrdb call in .xinitrc took care of that. I presume it's something to do with the chroot environment as the above all works fine on my other Mint laptop (edit: although of course that doesn't use .xinitrc).

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me all day to track down. I guess it's a good learning point, so I'll post it here. It's probably more obvious to those who've spent more time around shell than I have!

The trouble was the double square brackets in .xinitrc. Crouton invokes the chroot with sh, which points to dash. Dash, unlike bash, does not support double square brackets for tests. Using:

```
[ -f ~/.Xresources ] && xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

works fine.